# How to make a script that polls every second with POST or GET without lag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a notification center for my control manager system. If I use something like this:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.post("url", { data: 'value' }, function(result){
            // check for updates
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

the page is lagging all the time. Isn't it possible to do something like this 'on the background'? Without loading or lagging issues? If that is possible, that would be great! I tried several things but didn't have much effect.

Comment: You're sending 10 requests per second instead of once per second.

Comment: This code I made quick in the editor here. I forget to add another null.

Comment: If the server side ever takes more than 1 seconds to execute, running it every second may not help it run smoothly.

Comment: I'd wonder what `// check for updates` is doing. How exactly is it checking for updates?

Comment: As you see this post function returns the output of 'url'. The only thing it's doing: check if the new data is the same as the old, if not, update html and update notification count.

Comment: So you're getting some HTML content, and comparing it to the previous HTML content to see if it changed? It there's a lot of content, that can be very expensive, not to mention the fact that you're fetching the same content over and over. Instead, you could make a `HEAD` request, and check the `Last-Modified` header (as long as your server is setting that header). This will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

you should increase your interval time to something more reasonable than 10 times/second. maybe something like once per second with a value of `1000`

Comment: I realized that after looking at his interval time

Comment: The interval time was corrected in the comments and now in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called long-polling. Without knowing what your code is doing to the page, it is hard to tell what it causing lag on the page. Even so, polling every second can put a big load on your server as you scale.

You will want to increase your time interval. Something like once every 3-10 seconds won't adversely affect the user experience. People will not notice unless you are making a shared document editing or drawing application. It sounds like you are simply pushing notifications.

If you want web "real time" notifications, use WebSockets. You will still need to implement long-polling for browsers that do not support WebSockets: [details here under 'Browser compatibilities'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).

HTML5 Rocks has a good [intro to WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a guaranteed interval between your calls, instead of setInterval try using a setTimeout and call the same function that has your post/get code. Something like

```
function myTimeout() {
  //your code for post/get
  setTimeout(myTimeout, 1000);
}
```

What this does is guarantee the "Previous Interval" is complete before the next call to "myTimeout" which in turn has the post. This I believe, would not be guaranteed using setInterval, which in your case calls a function making the post every 1000 milli sec no matter what. With delays, the calls may not be spaced out by the desired interval(1000 milli sec). 
This still does not guarantee a fixed interval between calls though(if the call/response takes longer time than the specified interval).
Read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval under the heading "Dangerous usage"